# Not match Regex in between two character sequences with `String.split`

Tags: java, regex, scala, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm using Scala to work with some very messy data that it is not practical to clean. It comes in the form of delimited key-value pairs, something like this: `"a=1, b=2, c=3"`. I am using `String.split` to break up the String into key-value pairs. Most of the string value parts of these pairs are quoted if the need to be, so this works to not match `,` inside of quotes: `<string-instance>.split(", (?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")`

However, I have come across a `url` field that is neither quoted nor in all cases URL-encoded, so I have to deal with something like this:

`"foo=bar, url=http://city.com/Boston, MA US, is_test=false"`

In this case, I'm trying to match the comma-space after `bar` and the one after `US` and ignore the one after `Boston`. Fortunately, I can rely on these bad cases falling in between `url=` and `, is_test=` everywhere they occur (and that's about it). I've been banging my head on the Java regex tester here: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html and failing. The closest I could get with the above input was this:
`(?<!url=[.]{0,300}^, is_test), (?!.*, is_test)`, which only matched the comma-space after `US`, not the one after `bar`. The `{0,300}` is there to alleviate the problem of Java Regex not being able to handle potentially infinite look-behind expressions:
`java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length`

How can I solve this? Ideally, I could or the expression with the quoted comma-space ignoring one. One possibility too would be to match  in between `url=` and `, is_test` and replace them with `%20`. Unfortunately on that Regex expression, the closest I got was `(?<=url=.{0,300})\s(?!^\w*, is_test)` which matched the white-space right before `is_test` which I don't want to touch.

==edit==

My first example did not include a query string with a `=` which is a major part of my problem. Here is a more complete example of what I am dealing with:

`foo="bar, harbor", url=http://city.com/start_city=Boston, MA US&end_city=New York, NY US, is_test=false`

Comment: Are your keys always "proper" identifiers? That is, only letters, underscores and numbers?

Comment: I believe so, yes. It's too much data to inspect though, and here is where I got stuck. I find it unlikely that this would not be the case, but if I stumble across some, I can deal with it then. I am having the data generation fixed, but unfortunately I have a bunch of historical data to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your key value pair is separated by `=` and each of your pair is separated by a comma and some space, you can split on every comma which is just immediately before a `=` character using this regex,

```
,\s*(?=\w+=)
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yjK8mT/2)**

Check these Java codes which split your string at desired positions,

```
String[] data = "foo=\"bar, harbor\", url=http://city.com/start_city=Boston, MAUS&end_city=New York, NY US, is_test=false".split(",\\s*(?=\\w+=)");
Arrays.stream(data).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints,

```
foo="bar, harbor"
url=http://city.com/start_city=Boston, MAUS&end_city=New York, NY US
is_test=false
```

Let me know if this works for your cases and if not, please add the cases for which it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! This solved most of my cases, I didn't include a complex enough URL unfortunately, as url query strings often have `=` characters. Let me change the one above to:
`foo="bar, harbor", url=http://city.com/start_city=Boston, MA US&end_city=New York, NY US, is_test=false`
Your regex ignores the comma inside the quotes which works, and ignores the last comma-space in the URL, but not the first comma-space in the URL.

Comment: @kapunga in that case, try to replace the `[^,]` with `\w`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: You exactly stole my comment :) I was just writing that, based upon samples, we can use `\w+` as word character and use this regex `,\s*(?=\w+=)` which should solve this problem. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/yjK8mT/2) In my earlier regex, I allowed the key to contain any characters, which doesn't seem to be the actual case and restricting it to `\w+` seems reasonable to solve the problem.

Comment: This solved almost all my problems. I still have garbage, but it is a fraction of the non-garbage instead of the other way around. Definitely solves all the main cases I provided!

Comment: Just a quick followup. I eliminated almost all the rest of my garbage by changing the regex to this: `, (?=\w+=)` as I can rely on the correct split points being a comma followed by exactly one space.

Comment: @kapunga: Looks perfect. I used `\s*` to allow zero or more whitespaces but as you know your samples have exactly one space, it is indeed better to use a single space which gives you better performance. Let me know if you face any issues in any of your samples later anytime.